# Thymeleaf registration form throws IllegalStateException

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm a learner of Spring Boot 2.1.1. I made a registration form for my website.

I have a form on my register.html:

```
<form method="post" th:action="@{/reg}" th:object="${user}">
   <input type="text" name="email" th:field="*{emailAddress}">Email 
   address</input>
   <input type="text" name="password" th:field="* 
   {password}">Password</input>
   <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I've injected the User user object to the model in Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String register(Model model){
    System.out.println("marker 0");   
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    System.out.println("marker 1");
    return "register"; //returns the register.html view
}
```

These markers don't appearing on the console.

This is the code what should catch the data sent back from register.html:

```
@PostMapping("/reg")
    public String registerConfirmation(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, 
    Model model){
        // some code to proccess data
        return "registerconfirmation";
    }
```

User is a simple Entity with getters and setters:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

@Id
private Long id;


private String emailAddress;
private String password;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private int zipCode;


public User(){

}
```

Here is my Exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor 
plain target object for bean name 'user' available as request attribute
```

Concerning dependecies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

It throws always this exception, no matter what I do.
I've compared my code with several codes on the internet, I used every neccessary thing I think. I bet I'm wrong.
Maybe something is deprecated?
Please let me know if you need any more information, code, or stacktrace.

I'm really thankful for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove @ModelAttribute("user"), the @ModelAttribute is used to access request attribute, form data is in the request body or parameters.

Comment: I've deleted the Modelattribute annotation, but still there is the same problem. The HttpServletRequest request is used then? Which method can get the user object from the request? The getParameter returns only String. Thank you!

Comment: I was wrong. I read your code one more time carefully. I find some problem. First, you should generate the getter and setter method in User entity. Second, the name attribute of Input must same as User entity's field name, that is the name attribute of the first Input should be "emailAddress" instead of "email". Third, the @ModelAttribute you used before is correct, but it can be omitted.

Comment: ..
    public String getEmailAddress() {
        return this.emailAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param emailaddress the emailadress to set
     */
    public void setEmailAddress(String emailAddress) {
        this.emailAddress = emailAddress;
    }

I have the getters and setters already, I've written name property the smae as emailAddress, but it is still not working.